# Get value after particular character in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string as follows

```
$str = 'asdasdasd,sdfsdfsdf myNumber=1234, 2323 dfdfdf9898 sdfsdfdsf 234';
```

I'd like to return the digits within `myNumber=1234`.

Desired Outcome

```
$str = '1234';
```

I currently use the following regex `preg_replace('/\myNumber=\d+/', '', $y)` to replace when required, which works perfectly, but I'm not sure how I could use this to extract the numbers after the `=` sign from `myNumber=1234`?

Comment: You should extract with `preg_match` (with `\bmyNumber=(\d+)`). Or do you want a `preg_replace`  solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `preg_match` with the following regex:

```
\bmyNumber=(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tR1mE3/1)

The value will be available in Group 1. `(\d+)` matches and *captures* 1+ digits into a group that will be part of the resulting array.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/fbvSpN):

```
$re = '~\bmyNumber=(\d+)~'; 
$str = "asdasdasd,sdfsdfsdf myNumber=1234, 2323 dfdfdf9898 sdfsdfdsf 234"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function:

```
function getStringBetween($str, $from, $to)
{
    $sub = substr($str, strpos($str, $from) + strlen($from), strlen($str));
    return substr($sub, 0, strpos($sub, $to));
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
$a = getStringBetween($str, 'myNumber=', ',');
```

which will give you the output 1234 since its between the given strings.